# Exit if in a script, do not exit if using a terminal/tty

Tags: bash, shell

If the user is entering commands in a terminal, I want to echo an error statement, but I do not want the terminal to close, so I have this:

```
  if [[ "$fle" =~ [^a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
    echo "quicklock: lockname has invalid chars - must be alpha-numeric chars only."
    if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
        # if we are in a terminal just return, do not exit.
        return 1;
    else
        exit 1;
    fi
  fi
```

however the `if [[ -t 1 ]]; then` does not seem to work, the terminal window I am using just closes immediately, so I think `exit 1` is being called.

Comment: Is this piece of code run in a function? because `return` is only applicable there

Comment: exit in a function will exit, isn't that applicable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, so you run the above snippet in the command-line is it?

Comment: Why are you doing anything?  Why not just do the echo and be done with it?  Perhaps you need to show more complete code.

Comment: If you are running the script and still hit `exit 1` that could happen only if you `source` the script, (i.e. in the same shell) and not if you execute the script in a sub-shell

Comment: @user464502 if I am using a terminal, I can do nothing, if it's a shell script, I need to exit

Comment: I added a comment to your answer, almost there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-t` flag checks if any of the standard file descriptors are open, and specifically `[ -t 1 ]` will represent if the STDOUT is attached to `tty`, so when running from the terminal, it will always assert this condition as true.

Also the `return` keyword is applicable only when running a function to break out of it instead of terminating the shell itself. Your claim of terminal window closing because of hitting `exit 1` when running from script, could happen only if you `source` the script, (i.e. in the same shell) and will not happen if you execute the script in a sub-shell.

You can use a construct for a no-action in scripts by just doing `:` in the if condition as

```
if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
    # if we are in a terminal just return, do not exit.
    :
```

Also `-t` is defined by POSIX because of which you can do just `[ -t 1 ]`.

Comment: how can I check for `if [[ -t 0 && -t 1 ]]; then`...that syntax is wrong for some reason

Comment: @AlexanderMills: This seems to work for me `if [[ -t 0 && -t 1 ]]; then echo 'stdout & stdin connected to tty'; fi`

Comment: maybe that works...but ultimately I am trying to figure out if the code that's executing is being run in a terminal window or a shell script...I can't seem to programmatically determine that

Comment: maybe `tty -s`?

Comment: nah `if [ -t 1 ]` is not quite working - if I am in a terminal - it will still evaluate to true, so I am exiting when I do not want to.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Is a shell script being run from a terminal running in a terminal?  Normally the answer is yes.  How are you testing the script when it is not run from a terminal?  Does the 'interactivity' of the shell tell you?  The value of `$-` will contain `i` if the script is interactive and not otherwise: `case "$-" in (*i*) echo 'Interactive';; (*) echo 'Non-interactive';; esac` should tell you (and you can use `[[ … ]]` if you prefer).

Comment: well yes the shell script is run from the terminal...I guess I don't see how very many shell scripts do not have a grandparent that is terminal?

Comment: yes I see what you're saying..https://serverfault.com/questions/146745/how-can-i-check-in-bash-if-a-shell-is-running-in-interactive-mode

Comment: thanks that worked, I don't want to unaccept your answer but maybe you can explain what's going here...maybe I don't really understand what a tty is or what that means

Comment: @AlexanderMills: Feel free to unaccept it, because you ended up searching for something different than originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually what ended up working for me:

```
function on_conditional_exit {

   if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
       # if we are in a terminal just return, do not exit.
      echo -e "quicklock: since we are in a terminal, not exiting.";
      return 0;
   fi

   echo -e "quicklock: since we are not in a terminal, we are exiting...";
   exit 1;

}
```

the test is to see if we are in terminal or in a script somewhere...if we are interactive, we are in a terminal..

Comment: Appreciate you found what you were looking for. But this looks to be a total different context than the original question which is more about how you want to avoid the terminal being closed